# Получить данные из db.sqlite

Tags: php, sqlite

Пожалуйста, помогите получить данные по **item_id** из таблицы items.

Есть база данных db.sqlite следующего содержания:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подключаюсь к базе так (подключение есть):

```
include __DIR__ . '/libs/database.class.php';

$db = new DataBase(__DIR__ . '/db.sqlite');
```

Мне нужно получать из таблицы сведения (title, description, image) для заданного **item_id**.

Т.е. отправить в базу запрос item_id (пример: 123456) и получить из нее данные этого item_id (title, description, image).

Примерно так:

```
<p>$item['title'];</p>
<p>$item['item_id'];</p>
<p>$item['image'];</p>
<p>$item['description'];</p>
```

Помогите, пожалуйста.

У меня ничего не получается вообще, постоянный NULL

Comment: Никто не видел вашего кода, поэтому вряд ли смогут помочь

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!7/92d4a/1 если у вас `item_id` не пустое поле, то где-то в коде. Ковычки в имени таблицы, зачем?

Comment: item_id мне известен изначально, мне нужно с его помощью получить остальные данные. Кавычки видимо упущение разработчика, гляну, где они проставляются.

Comment: `"SELECT * from items WHERE item_id=$item_id;"` - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!7/92d4a/2 вот так.

Comment: Kosta B. Здорово, спасибо! Это то, что мне нужно. Теперь буду разбираться, как выполнить этот запрос внутри php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Мне нужно получать из таблицы сведения (title, description, image) для заданного item_id.

Запрос выглядит вот так:

```
"SELECT * from items WHERE item_id=$item_id;"
```

- Имя таблицы не надо помещать в ковычки.